# BitPay / Copay's Weird Bitcoin Cash Address Format

Tags: address, bitcoin-cash, bitpay, copay, address-format

My CoPay wallet shows my Bitcoin Cash address as `CTGUTUgVAwHugpf4CyyjAvj8DCFkE4tpEq`. What's going on? I thought both Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash addresses start with `1` or `3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer, while correct, is outdated. While BitPay did use a proprietary format early on, we quickly adopted the CashAddr format for Bitcoin Cash/BCH transactions.

Example: bitcoincash:pqkh9ahfj069qv8l6eysyufazpe4fdjq3u4hna323j

You can use our address translator to get the correct format for any address (https://bitpay.github.io/address-translator).

References: https://blog.bitpay.com/cashaddr-bch-format/

Answer (score 2):

It's a new address format for Bitcoin Cash proposed by BitPay, to prevent BTC/BCC address confusion. It's not widely used, currently.

- The old addresses that start with `1` (P2PKH) are converted to addresses that start with `C`
- The old addresses that start with `3` (P2SH) are converted to addresses that start with `H`

You can use this "address translator" to translate the addresses: https://bitpay.github.io/address-translator/

References:

BitPay blog post: https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004671663-BitPay-s-Adopted-Conventions-for-Bitcoin-Cash-Addresses-URIs-and-Payment-Requests

Comment: It’s worth noting that this really should have happened earlier, BCash sharing the version bytes with bitcoin was to intentionally cause confusion.